# using ERC token to login website

Tags: web3js, erc-20

recently I want to write some website login program using ERC tokens ,can anyone show me the way to do that ?
an idea or a route are both good for me

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I think you would be better off to [login with metamask](https://www.toptal.com/ethereum/one-click-login-flows-a-metamask-tutorial) or equivalent. Logging in with an ERC token makes little very sense to me. Please clarify what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Now when you login with 'metamask' you have to cryptographically prove that you own an Ethereum address, not sure how to replicate that for a ERC Token, especially with ERC20 tokens. Are you asking about ERC721 tokens?

I mean you could have a smart contract that handles authentication that subtracts ERC20 tokens every time a user logs in. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: actually what I just mean is that , compared to login website using username and pwd ,I wanna use ERC875 tokens

Comment: I mean you can mix and match, require a user to login with metamask and only give access if they have a certain erc875 token balance, that shouldnt be that hard to inplement

Comment: what I'm thinking was ,  when handle a signup ,use publicAddress as erc875_token recipient address ,and only give access to sign in when its publicAddress.balance i== 0